# Use OpenStreetMap (OSM) with .Net Maui control "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"

Tags: .net, openstreetmap, maui

With the MAUI control [Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps/) released in .net 7.0 it is possible to load Google Maps into the control. I tried this with the sample project [MapDemo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo) and it works very well.

I would like to use OSM (OpenStreetMap) as map source instead of Google Maps. Is there any support for OSM with this control?

Comment: I assume that would require editing the source. Looks like it is part of Maui github. You could create an issue there, asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because the MAUI map handler `MapElementHandler` uses the default map provider of the system:

Android:

> Xamarin.GooglePlay.Services.Maps

iOS:

> Microsoft.iOS.MKMapView

Alternatively use the [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-7.0) Control and additional libraries to display another map or [MapsUI](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui) (Preview).

Answer (score 2):

Following a similar process. Closest I could find was

- https://mapsui.com/
- http://mapsui.com/documentation/getting-started-maui.html

Comment: There is a bug where the map control displays only background when visiting the page repeatedly which makes it unusable. Have you found a working scenario?